# How to compare Column data and replace text using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my table schema

```
Table1
 {
    Column1 nVarchar(MAX),
    Column2 nVarchar(MAX),
    Column3 nVarchar(MAX),
    Column4 nVarchar(MAX),
    Column5 nVarchar(MAX),
    Column6 nVarchar(MAX),
    Column7 nVarchar(MAX),
    Column8 nVarchar(MAX),
    Column9 nVarchar(MAX),

 }
```

How shall i compare Column1 with Column2 , Column3 ... Column9 and if the Column2  data is same as Column1 make the Column2 Empty and do the same with other columns

Comment: Should all duplicates be removed or just contiguous duplicates?

Comment: All the duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't be bothered to type out all 9 columns on IPad but the below will do what you need.

You need to add the other 7 columns into the `set`, `values` and `pivot` following the pattern of the first two.

```
UPDATE t1
 SET Column1 = [1],
     Column2 = [2]
FROM #table1 t1
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  DENSE_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(Idx)) AS Rnk, 
        ColumnValue
FROM
(
VALUES(1, Column1),(2, Column2)) V(Idx, ColumnValue)
WHERE ColumnValue IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ColumnValue
) D
PIVOT (MAX(ColumnValue) FOR Rnk IN ([1], [2])) AS P
) ca
```